# jQuery returning multiple functions doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am working a simple form validation and I have 3 functions where I check the input text fields, a select field and 2 radio buttons. For each group I have made a function, so 3 functions.

I have tested the functions on its own and they are working. But if I use them all 3 together at the end of my script, only one of them works.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do?

```
// Form validation
$(function() {
    function wz_validation() {
        var ok = true;

        $('input[validate="true"]').each(function() {
            if($(this).val() == '') {
                ok = false;
                $(this).addClass('red_border');
            }
            else $(this).removeClass('red_border');
        });

        return ok;
    }

    // Check Bank select box on checkout page
    function wz_val_select() {
        if($(".payment select")) {
            if($(".payment select option:selected").val() == "") {
                $(".payment select").addClass('red_border');
                return false;
            }
            else{
                $(".payment select").removeClass('red_border'); 
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    function wz_radio_shipping() {
        var form = $("#shipping_form");
        if(form.length) {
            if(form.find('input[name=wz_shipping]:checked').length == 0) {
                $("#checkout_shipping").addClass('red_border');
                return false;   
            }
            else{
                $("#checkout_shipping").removeClass('red_border');
                return true;    
            }
        }
    }

    var wz_form = $('#wz_form1, #wz_form2, #wz_form3, #wz_form7');

    $(wz_form).submit(function() {
        return wz_validation() && wz_radio_shipping() && wz_val_select();
    });
});
```

Comment: Check this out: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/ - You might have to load one then another then another.

Answer (score 4):

`&&` is a [short circuit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation) operator. It prevents the evaluation of `b` in `a && b` when `a` is falsy.

If you want to have all three functions called even when some of them return `false`, and if you only return boolean values, use `&`. As `&` makes `0` or `1`, you might want to convert the result to a boolean with `!!` :

```
    return !!(wz_validation() & wz_radio_shipping() & wz_val_select());
```

You might also want to write it more explicitly :

```
$(wz_form).submit(function(e) {
    var good = true;
    good &= wz_validation();
    good &= wz_radio_shipping();
    good &= wz_val_select();
    if (!good)  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: For those of us (like myself) who did not realize this was in Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FBitwise_Operators#.26_%28Bitwise_AND%29

Comment: Okay, but the problem is that if I use "&" the functions do there job and give my errors, but the form submits always. So I placed the functions in an if statement and say: if (functions & .. &) return true, else return false. But now the form never submits..

Comment: With your last edit I got the same problem. the functions do their job but I can't submit anymore.

Comment: @Robbert Are you sure the three functions return true ?

Comment: @dystroy Mmm I am not a hero in jQuery but in my opinion they return true. Is there some way I can check this for 100%?

Comment: @Robbert Add lines like `console.log('wz_validation:', wz_validation());`. Or [debug](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Comment: @dystroy I have tried your last more explicitly edit, but got the same problem. Added the console.log (never worked with this) but I now see the red borders from my functions the whole time.

Comment: Yes I can but my fields are divided over multiple pages, so maybe it is an idea to give you the url to my project?

Comment: @dystroy I opened my chrome developer tool and opened console and it gives me not always true.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43268/discussion-between-robbert-and-dystroy)